# Convergence of a sequence solution mistake?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

In the attached image, that I have found I believe there is a mistake on the first line. Could anyone else please confirm my suspicions, thanks.

That the end of the first line should instead be $\dfrac{2}{n} - \dfrac{3}{n^2}$

[image]

Thank you

Comment: No; $|a-b|\leq |a|-|b|$ is not necessarily true; take $a=1, b=2$.

Comment: Of course thanks for this ^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modulus of (-x) is x. As the user dlc commented what you posted can be written although what you yourself said is also acceptable.